# Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) + Tomcat7 --- Cannot create a server using the selected type

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, eclipse-indigo

Setup:

- Eclipse 3.7 + the WEB tools from the indigo update site
- Tomcat7
- Ubuntu

Problem:

When I try to add a new Tomcat 7 server in the server perspective in Eclipse I get the following error:

```
"Cannot create a server using the selected type"
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447289/problem-creating-a-tomcat-6-server-in-eclipse-form-ubuntu didn't helped?

Comment: You should accept the answer below as the advice in it fixes your problem.

Comment: Did this issue happen after removing Server?

Answer (score 135):

This is a known issue.To resolve this error, try one or all of the following:

1. Go to `Window–>Preferences–>Server–>Runtime Environments` and fix the broken path/link for the server.
2. Rename the `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs` to `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs.bak` (or you can delete this file). This file can be found at `\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings`
3. Rename the `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs` to `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs.bak` (or delete the file).  This file also can be found at the same location as above.

Comment: what if i cannot found org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs and org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs under\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings ?

Comment: Renaming the files .bak won't work. You need to either rename in a different way, move away or delete them.

Comment: Using the method 1 `Go to Window–>Preferences–>Server–>Runtime Environments and fix the broken path/link for the server.` works. The strange thing is that once you have added a path that's not correct anymore, even if you remove the relevant `Server Runtime Environment`, you will not be able to select the relevant Server in the `new server wizard`, you MUST fix that path before doing so.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am tired to death of damned Eclipse's issues. It seems that it has got nothing but issues. It's a crap.

Comment: I have deleted `tomcat7` in `Window–>Preferences–>Server–>Runtime Environments` and this don't helped. Then I removed `rm ./org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core_1.1.301.v20111010_1242.jar` and `rm ./org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.ui_1.1.200.v20100418.jar` and seems now I can't see tomcat in list at new server creation, so something get broken.

Comment: Even uninstalling and installing `Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools`,
`Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools`,
`Eclipse Web Developer Tools`,
`JST Server Adapters` bring me back to step `I have deleted tomcat7 in Window–>Preferences–>Server–>Runtime Environments`

Answer (score 3):

A different resolution of the same problem that worked for me. I share it here it might be helpful for someone.

I have 
- Eclipse Juno
- Tomcat 7
- Windows 7

This is what I did

Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Installed JREs and I've got jre7 added and selected here. So I added jre6 by pressing Add button(If not installed or you ran a java update, just download and install jre6). And select jre6 instead of jre7.

Now go to Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment > Press Add and add Tomcat 7.

You're done now.

Answer (score 1):

After trying aleroot's solution without success, VonC's comment on the question was what fixed it for me. So follow the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447289/problem-creating-a-tomcat-6-server-in-eclipse-form-ubuntu) if you hit a wall. Remember to remove the old Tomcat configuration from Runtime Environments afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I had two tomcat 7 runtime configurations added to my Server's Runtime configurations tab. Deleted the duplicate one and fixed the path to the only tomcat 7 which was installed in my system under `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0` and this solved my problem of adding a new server in the servers tab.

1. Go to `Window` > `Preferences` > `Server` > `Runtime Environments` and update the server runtime environment path to change the broken path for the server by clicking `Edit`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above solutions worked for me. Neither of the files listed exist in that location or anywhere else on my machine. I tried backing up all the files in the .settings folder and restarting Eclipse, but still got the same error.

The only thing that worked was to reinstall Tomcat.

Comment: That is pretty interesting. This seems to happen about once per month, so I'll try that next time!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to the server running in some other Java(TM) Platform.

1. Start Task manager->Processes->Select Java(TM)
2. Click "End Processes".

After finishing this procedure you can add the server without any error.

Comment: I guess this should be comment

Answer (score 0):

I removed the files mentioned above...still no luck. On a whim, I decided to download and install NetBeans. I was up and running with Postgres DB and Apache server running, etc. in just a few minutes! No extra downloads, etc.

Anyway, switching to Netbeans is what worked for me. Goodbye Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to remove the Servers directory if was already created. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the working steps mentioned in the others answers, and even if did not work then,

**Change eclipse, workspace and tomcat directory.** [tested only for Windows7]

I know somebody might say that is not correct, but above step did work for me.

It took me 4 hours to find this brute force method solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed Tomcat 7 with apt-get in a Debian/Ubuntu system, the cleanest solution to this problem is to assign the user under which Eclipse is running to the **tomcat7 group**.

If for example that user's username is `pippo` then you just need to run:

```
sudo adduser pippo tomcat7
```

Note: you need to log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.