# Setting up Eclipse with Tomcat 7 in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, tomcat, archlinux

I have recently installed [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) and using [Pacman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacman_%28package_manager%29) I installed [Eclipse](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Eclipse) and [Tomcat 7](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tomcat) using the relevant guides in the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Main_Page). I followed the guide *[Apache Tomcat Eclipse Integration, An Illustrated Quick Start Guide](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-eclipse)* to integrate the two together.

To sum it up, I did the following:

1. Installed **WPT** from the Eclipse **Install New Software** feature.
2. Opened the new **Dynamic Web Project** wizard
3. During the wizard I selected *Apache Tomcat v7.0* and set the **Tomcat installation directory** to */usr/share/tomcat7*
4. Completed the wizard
5. Right clicked on the server tab (located at the bottom of the IDE) and clicked on the new server dialogue

In this dialouge is were I encounter an issue. When I choose **Tomcat v7.0 Server** the error *Cannot create a server using the selected type* pops up.

I'm suspecting that it might be a permission issue since I am not running Eclipse via root, but I am not sure how to set them up for this scenario. Other than that I am not sure if maybe it is a directory issue, that is, Eclipse is trying to locate a specific folder which is located somewhere else.

I am uncertain if this is an Arch Linux question specifically or Linux in general.

Comment: Try assigning the group tomcat7 to your user's groups as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15505124/334569

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before this sounds very much like a permission issue. Ensure that the user running Eclipse has read and execute privileges for Tomcat. Also you should check that the Tomcat server can start properly without running from Eclipse. Verify that it can bind to the default 8080 port, etc.

You can check the Tomcat logs for the details and the configuration file for Tomcat is usually in the `<tomcat base>/conf/server.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

As you already suspect, it is probably a permission issue. Check that your user is added to the tomcat group and make sure that scripts in `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin` are readable and executable by tomcat group members. Also it is important that tomcat group has read access to `/usr/share/tomcat7/conf` files and of course the permission to enter the directories itself.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a tomcat group but rather a specific tomcat user.

Comment: @Drahcir Then create it with `groupadd tomcat` and then add your user to that group with `usermod -a -G tomcat youruser`. You would need to relogin after that.