# Can not run Tomcat 7 from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am using Eclipse EE Helios.
I wanted to deploy to Tomcat 7 a project I created.

(I have already downloaded Tomcat and created a dynamic project)

I opened the `Server View` in Eclipse and I pressed `New` to define a new Tomcat instance within Eclipse.

In the dialog for `New Server` I selected `Tomcat v7.0 Server` but I saw an error indication on the top of the window

> Cannot create a server using the selected type

If I press the link `Download additional server adapters` I see several options e.g. for Geronimo, GlassFish etc but not for
Tomcat 7.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Also see this Stack article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025841/eclipse-3-7-indigo-tomcat7-cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-typ

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually downloaded and installed Tomcat? It doesn't come with Eclipse by default.

Here are some directions on setting up Tomcat in Eclipse: http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/apache/tomcat/tutorial_tomcat_eclipse/index.htm

And you can download Tomcat here: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Comment: Of course? Since you are just now setting it up, and you never said you downloaded it, how was I to know that?

Comment: I said in the OP that I already created a project to be deployed as WAR.Anyway, you may be correct and I was not clear.I will update the post.Thank you

Comment: Hi cratylus, i am getting same issue. did u got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Tomcat7 Runtime. In project -> right click -> properties -> Targeted runtimes -> new. It will create a second version from the same server. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From a Mac prospective, but should be the same on windows.

Here a brief guide:

1. Open Server window
2. New > Server
3. Select **Tomcat v7.0 Server**
4. Select **Server runtime environment**. Press **add**

[image]

5.Select the folder where you extracted the server files that you have downloaded

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try From Eclipse

Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime environments

Add or modify configuration parameters of server Tomcat 7.0 particurlaly the installation path of the Tomcat 7 directory.

It works for me !

Answer (score 0):

Project facets contain something incompatible to be deployed to Tomcat 7

Go to Project properties -> Project Facets
disable/downgrade uncompatible project facets