# Tomcat Installation on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, tomcat7

Tomcat 7.0 on Eclipse hadn't been running fine on Eclipse. I removed it so that I can start from scratch for a "clean" install. 
I did so merely by deleting its entry from the Servers folder under projects.

Now, when I go for re-installing it, I can't get passed the first window on "new-server definition" wizard. Tomcat 7 is listed as one of 
the servers I can install. 
However, Eclipse is disabling the "Server Name"-- not allowing me to give a name to it or giving a default "Server Name" itself so that I can proceed with the "Next" button which also is disabled. 
This is only for Tomcat 7.0. The previous versions of Tomcat and some other 
servers I tried on the menu are fine and don't have this problem.

I tried "Download additional server adapters" in that same window. Nothing shown seemed necessary. 
All I saw of Apache there are some Geronimo adapters. 
Besides, I wasn't asked for anything of the kind to proceed during the previous install.

I've also tried

- changing the path names in my Windows environment and
- moving the Tomcat folder to someplace else-- or renaming it rather
- restarting Eclipse to clear its environment in case that's an issue

to "fool" Eclipse so that it won't see anything from the previous install and start fresh.

Is there anything more than what I've done to remove Tomcat on Eclipse?

I'm even thinking about installing Eclipse from scratch to get around it-- although i don't think it would be necessary.

I have Tomcat 7 installed & running fine outside Eclipse in my DOS Command prompt.

I am using Eclipse Juno on Windows 7.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Tomcat-on-Eclipse has been burning my time for days by now and it still is.

EDIT-- P.S.: Would this be the 7.0 setup? Whenever I look around, see eg. [Can not run Tomcat 7 from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819674/can-not-run-tomcat-7-from-eclipse?rq=1)
I see someone having something with Tomcat 7.0. But there aren't that many installation problems on Tomcat6.0 or other versions.

Answer (score 1):

On Eclipse Main-menu,

Windows > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment > Add

asked for the folder that Tomcat is installed in.

Seems to be working-- for now.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had the same issue, when I had deleted my old tomcat server, and was attempting to install a new one.

Make sure to **edit** your existing Server Runtime Environment to point to the directory where your installed tomcat server is located!