# Running web project with tomcat server from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, jersey

i was doing a web service using jersey framework and i was following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) example. I installed tomcat and and also tomcat plug in into the eclipse. But while i tried to run the project by right click on the project and go to run as-->run on server, then i didn't get "next" or "finish" button active as you can see in the image below. Also when i am trying to enter servername, then it is not taking any key type. So any idea why this is happening ? If any more details you need guys please let me know. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: you forgot the image :p

Comment: @emgsilva sorry added..

Comment: so you need to add a server name and the 'Next' button will be activated

Comment: Yes... server name (then have the Tomcat distro to point to) should allow you to set your tomcat up in Eclipse.

Comment: @user2310289 u r right, but i already tried entering server name, it's not taking any name. I mean while i m typing the name nothing is getting inputted in that text box.

Comment: Try to configure "Runtime environments" (define where the Tomcat is in your system - Preferences / Server / Runtime Environments) before doing this (add new Server)... but normally you should have a link from this window to do that... what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @emgsilva i am using eclipse juno..

Comment: did you try to setup the "runtime environment", and also as suggested in the answer bellow review the "dynamic web module"?

Comment: @emgsilva i will try and let u know. thanks

Comment: @emgsilva tried but no help... :(

Comment: this looks like a problem defining the "runtime environment" of you Tomcat... In principle this should be possible and easy to set in your project, right-click: "Preferences / Server / Runtime Environments"... but it seems that some people do have "similar" problems see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423593/eclipse-4-2-juno-cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-in-tomcat-7... I never had such problems, but maybe it helps, cannot see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dynamic Web Module version might be problem. You downgrade your project module to 2.5 and try.

[image]