# How to create a new server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I created a new server in eclipse but then I deleted it for some reason and now I couldn't create a new one. I got Apache Tomcat 7 but when I select Tomcat v7 server from list, Server name field is not editable.Also buttons are not working(finish,next).

[image: My screenshot :D]

Comment: have you made sure the installed runtime preference is still valid?

Comment: @nitind I have found that this is a bug in eclipse. I will change my IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Close eclipse and delete these two files and start eclipse. It worked for me.

```
 cd ~/eclipse_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/
 rm org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
 rm org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
```

If there are any more errors coming up refer to this [blogpost](http://jayachandra-reddy.blogspot.com/2013/03/configuring-tomcat-and-elipse-in-ubuntu.html)
or [Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) 'Cannot create a server using the selected type' in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423593/eclipse-4-2-juno-cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-in-tomcat-7)

Similar question :[Eclipse add Tomcat 7 blank server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791843/eclipse-add-tomcat-7-blank-server-name)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the workspace in the Navigator View (or in Windows Explorer) you see a project/folder called 'Servers'. It contains your server configurations. Empty that folder and recreate your Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, just correct the user rights, for example in Ubuntu with the command:

```
sudo chown -R yourname:yourgroup /opt/apache-tomcat-8*
```